# Intermittent error when displaying the drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble when displaying a dropdown menu.

fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/GxrSk/

The Simple HTML code:

```
 <nav>
       <ul id="top-menu">
       <li class="parent">
            <a href="#">MENU ITEM</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li><a href="#">ITEM 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">ITEM 2</a></li>
            </ul>
       </li>
       </ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}


nav { margin-top: 28px; }

#top-menu li { position: relative; }

#top-menu > li { display: inline-block; margin-left: 40px; }

#top-menu li a { font-family: "Ubuntu Condensed", sans-serif; color: #000; font-size: 16px; text-transform: uppercase; }

ul.sub-menu { display: none; top: 26px; position: absolute; min-width: 137px; z-index: 9999; }

ul.sub-menu > li > a { text-align: center; display: block; }

#top-menu li:hover > ul.sub-menu { display: block; }
```

Look, the problem is that sometimes I can navigate the menu and some times when I try to enter it, the menu has hidden.

If someone can't understand, post in the comments below.

Comment: Try decreasing the top value in `ul.sub-menu`

Comment: don't work, =[ test more then one time

Comment: I decreased the top to 19px, as mentioned by j08691, and it seems to work now.

Comment: when put 19px, work, ok. but, there is no way that depends not change the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change top to padding top.

```
padding-top: 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make `ul.sub-menu { top:20px; }`

```
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}


nav { margin-top: 28px; }

#top-menu li { position: relative; }

#top-menu > li { display: inline-block; margin-left: 40px; }

#top-menu li a { font-family: "Ubuntu Condensed", sans-serif; color: #000; font-size: 16px; text-transform: uppercase; }

ul.sub-menu { display: none; top: 20px; position: absolute; min-width: 137px; z-index: 9999; }

ul.sub-menu > li > a { text-align: center; display: block; }

#top-menu li:hover > ul.sub-menu { display: block; }
```

Comment: There is no way that depends not change the top?

Comment: give it width and height for the UL of sub menu and give it padding i think it will work try it

Answer (score 0):

keep decreasing the top-value in `ul.sub-menu` until it works.

Comment: There is no way that depends not change the top?

Comment: yes, there is by adding `ul.submenu { margin-top: -6px; }` in the css :)

Comment: if you are reluctant to change top and using it for spacing only, you should simply use `padding-top: 6px` instead of `top: 26px; position:absolute;`

Comment: Tks man, but the Diego Alves answer solve my problem, and it's first. But thank you so much.